# How do I cross check whether an Imported a jar file is successfully added or not in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am supposed to replace existiong API with Apache POI 3.16. I have downloaded `poi-3.16.jar` and have added it in my Eclipse `libs` folder. How do I check if it is successfully added or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go on configure  buildpath and see that jar is there or not with correct path.

1. right click on project
2. configure build path go on libraries
3. now check you jar folder or jar file is present or not.
4. or you can check by use one of class of this jar like HSSFWorkbook if it is imported means this jar is added successfully otherwise you need to add.

Comment: Thank you Khandal. Checked and found ok.

Comment: click on up sign that answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you import classes from it and attempt using them, does it work or not? There's nothing more to it.
If you replaced an older version of the same lib, remove the old and rebuild the project.

But, above all, do yourself a favor and use Maven or Gradle or any other build tool with dependency management and just add the correct dependency. Manually maintaining the classpath is infernally error prone.

Answer (score 0):

First, open the jar file with any program that you would use to open a zip file.  Drill down through the folders until you find a class to represent that jar file.
Note the package plus class name.

Open a "Open Type" message dialog.  This is usually at the shortcut, Ctrl + Shift + T, or in the menu at Navigate -> Open Type.  Enter the package name plus classname in the dialog.  Select the class and it should show the name of the jar file at the bottom.

If Open Type is disabled, you may need to enable it through Window -> Customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability -> Java Navigation in the "Available command groups"